# Keyboard not dissmissing

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

In my view controller i added a text field as below.

```
txt1 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 70, 20)];
txt1.delegate = self;
txt1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
[self.view addSubview:txt1];
[txt1 release];
```

I set `UITextFieldDelegate` in `.h` file. I write

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

to dissmiss my keyboard.But it not firing delegate method.
Any help!!!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sending the `resignFirstResponder` message?

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
     [textField resignFirstResponder];
     return YES;
}
```

Comment: i send  [textField resignFirstResponder] inside textFieldShouldReturn. But the delegate method itself not firing while i tapping return button.

Comment: I did the same in AppllicationDelegate. Here i added the textfield in window. It is working. What is the reason behind that. Any idea?